# How to add custom dimensions in React Ga?

Tags: google-analytics, react-ga

How to add custom dimensions in `ReactGA` (event)?

I tried below approach :

```
GoogleAnalytics.set({
 email: 'my_email',
 id: 'my_id', 
})
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using below snippet:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

ReactGA.set({
  'email': 'my_email',
  'id': 'my_id'
})
```